# How to simulate a race between threads which run in parallel?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make a thread race, but my threads run in order instead of running in parallel ...After a thread finishes the race , it has to inform the context and the context should announce the winner and stop the race . How can I repair this ?

```
My ThreadRaceClass:

public class ThreadRace {
    List<ThreadRaceCompetitor> competitors = new ArrayList<>(10);

    public ThreadRace() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            competitors.add(new ThreadRaceCompetitor());
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        competitors.forEach(ThreadRaceCompetitor::run);
    }
}
```

The ThreadCompetitor object:

```
public class ThreadRaceCompetitor implements Runnable {
    private static final ThreadRaceContext context = new ThreadRaceContext();
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int raceNumber;
    private int progress = 0;


    public ThreadRaceCompetitor() {
        raceNumber = count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + raceNumber + " is running with " + i + " speed and has covered " + progress + " kilometers / 20" );
            try {
                sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progress++;
        }
        synchronized (context) {
            context.announceWinner(raceNumber);
        }
    }

    public int getRaceNumber() {
        return raceNumber;
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }
}
```

And the context:

```
public class ThreadRaceContext extends Thread {

    public void announceWinner(int raceNumber) {
        System.out.println("Competitor with number " + raceNumber + " won the race");
    }
}
```

Comment: Threads take a long time to start, many milli-seconds, and they can perform thousands of operations in that time.

Comment: You need one instance of `Thread` for each, well, *thread*. Where are you creating those `Thread` instances?

Comment: in my ThreadRace constructor class

Comment: Your `public class ThreadRaceContext extends Thread` is, btw., completely senseless.

Comment: @Gustavo No, in `ThreadRace` you are not creating any threads.

Comment: You have thread objects, but you are not start()ing them and even if you did, that would call the `run()` method which doesn't do anything in your case.

Comment: @JimmyB There is one thread `private static final ThreadRaceContext context` but it is not start()ed

Comment: Notice that `Runnable` is *not* a `Thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are not creating any Thread here. Just by implementing runnable will not make an instance of a class Thread. Using your runnable you have to create an instance of Thread and start it.

One way to achieve this with your existing code is to make your `ThreadRaceCompetitor` extend Thread and in your `ThreadRace` class's `start` method  call `start` method on each `ThreadRaceCompetitor` in the list instead of calling `run` directly.

Comment: Please don't extend `Thread`. Use `new Thread( new ThreadRaceCompetitor() )` instead.

Comment: @JimmyB If a class's objective is solely to be a Thread then it is absolutely fine to extend Thread which is the case here.

Comment: Bad style, don't get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the start-method. Then it should work.

```
public void start() {
    competitors.forEach(ThreadRaceCompetitor::start); // not sure if that is possible...
}

 //alternative
 public void start() {
    for(ThreadRaceCompetitor c: competitors) {
         c.start();
 }
}
```

Comment: I did that, now my threads start at random but the progress attribute doesn't increment ... this is the output now :

Comment: Thread 2 is running with 0 speed and has covered 0 kilometers / 20
Thread 1 is running with 0 speed and has covered 0 kilometers / 20
Thread 3 is running with 0 speed and has covered 0 kilometers / 20
Thread 4 is running with 0 speed and has covered 0 kilometers / 20
Thread 5 is running with 0 speed and has covered 0 kilometers / 20
Thread 6 is running with 0 speed and has covered 0 kilometers / 20

Comment: @Gustavo Thats how you have coded it, if you expect something else, change your code. There is no magic behind it, check the flow of your code.